# Executable file not opening after signing

Tags: windows, code-signing

I built my EXE yesterday. When the EXE file is unsigned, it works normally. When I signs my file with DigiCert code signing certificate, after I sign my file, I opens it, it does not open anymore.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @harrymc No errors, it just doesn't open.

Comment: DigiCert have client support which can probably give more information about signing.